# Not all code paths return a value - error

Tags: c#

I have the following code to read if data exist. I want to return true or false but C# compiler says: "*not all code paths return a value*" and red error line shown on my method name `ReadDV`.

The code is:

```
public bool ReadDV(string ReadCommand)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection SCO = ConnectionClass.getconnection();
        SqlCommand delCmd = new SqlCommand(ReadCommand, SCO);
        if (SCO.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            SCO.Open();
        SqlDataReader r = delCmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (r.Read())
        {
            if (SCO.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                SCO.Close();

            r.Close();
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

### The `ConnectionClass.getconnection()` code is a part of a method for returning the connection string and it is working ok.

I will add 2nd part of my code for calling this method : it doesn't work when read is null

```
string RUSERSSV = @"select * from USERSSV  where Users = ........;
            DB db = new DB();   // calling method

        if (comboBox1.Text != "")
        {
            if (db.ReadDV(RUSERSSV)==true)  // this is the mention part
            {
                string IUSERSSV = @"update USERSSV set Users =    // insert fired if read is true
                db.insert(IUSERSSV);
                Save.Form(this);
            }
            else
            {
                string IUSERSSV = @"insert into USERSSV  // update fired if read false
                db.insert(IUSERSSV);
                Save.Form(this);
            }
```

Comment: What is returned is `r.Read()` returns `false`?

Comment: You forgot return true or return false in else case of 'if (r.Read())'

Comment: For more information, read [Methods (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: it should be return true

Comment: thanks all , all following answers is ok and removed my error but after I will call ,it doesnot work

Comment: string RUSERSSV = @"select * from USERSSV  where    // string for read method  , DB db = new DB();   // for calling read method  , if (db.ReadDV(RUSERSSV))
                { then update .............. else
inert ..........

Answer (score 4):

You have return statement in `if` that **may or may not execute** you should have one `return` statement that *must* execute. Putting return after catch will probably remove the error if it get executed unconditionally. You can use a bool variable to store the value to return and return that variable.

```
bool success = false;
try
{

    SqlConnection SCO = ConnectionClass.getconnection();
    SqlCommand delCmd = new SqlCommand(ReadCommand, SCO);
    if (SCO.State != ConnectionState.Open) SCO.Open();
    SqlDataReader r = delCmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (r.Read())
    {
        if (SCO.State != ConnectionState.Closed) SCO.Close();
        r.Close();     
        success = true;     
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return false;
}
return success;
```

Answer (score 1):

Place the return statement outside the **if( r.Read() )** block

```
if (r.Read())
{
     if (SCO.State != ConnectionState.Closed) SCO.Close();
     r.Close();

}
// other code
return true;
```

Basically, there should be a return statement right before your function ends.

Comment: Your code modifies the behavior of the method to someting unintended, as it will return true even if no data is read.

Comment: Agreed. A flag should be used here. What I intend to say is that the user should have a return statement outside the `if` blocks.

Comment: That is not even true. He certainly could do `if (...) { ... return true; } else { return false; }`

Comment: I did that both of them but if database has no data it will return nothing , I want read 2 field of table on sql , if it is null or doesn't find , insert statement fired , else update fired

Comment: Not sure why the provided solutions are not working. can you share some more code?

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't returning anything, when `if(r.Read())` is false.
You could fix your code following way:

```
public bool ReadDV(string ReadCommand)
{
    bool returnValue = false;
    try
    {
        SqlConnection SCO = ConnectionClass.getconnection();
        SqlCommand delCmd = new SqlCommand(ReadCommand, SCO);
        if (SCO.State != ConnectionState.Open) SCO.Open();
        SqlDataReader r = delCmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (r.Read())
        {
            if (SCO.State != ConnectionState.Closed) SCO.Close();
            r.Close();
            returnValue = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        returnValue = false;
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Above code now always returns false, when r.Read was false or an exception was catched.

Comment: yes it always returns false and if statement is denaied

Answer (score 1):

I propose this, it's a cleaner solution and it'll prevent issues like the yours:

```
public bool ReadDV(string ReadCommand)
{
    bool result = false;
    try
    {
        SqlConnection SCO = ConnectionClass.getconnection();
        SqlCommand delCmd = new SqlCommand(ReadCommand, SCO);
        if (SCO.State != ConnectionState.Open) SCO.Open();
        SqlDataReader r = delCmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (r.Read())
        {
            if (SCO.State != ConnectionState.Closed) SCO.Close();
            r.Close();
            result = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: return result;
is out of if , and return always false

Comment: whats about r.Read() what does this return?

Answer (score 1):

```
public bool ReadDV(string ReadCommand)
{
    bool bRetVal = false;
    try
    {
        SqlConnection SCO = ConnectionClass.getconnection();
        SqlCommand delCmd = new SqlCommand(ReadCommand, SCO);
        if (SCO.State != ConnectionState.Open) SCO.Open();
        SqlDataReader r = delCmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (r.Read())
        {
            if (SCO.State != ConnectionState.Closed) SCO.Close();
            r.Close();
            bRetVal = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        bRetVal = false;
    }
    return bRetVal
}
```

Try to initialize the return values in a variable and then change the value depending on your code path and just have one return statement in the end, that way you dont need to have multiple return statements. (The error is because you missed return statement for that function - Every possible code path should return a value for that function)

Answer (score 0):

thanks all

I made it with following :

---

public bool ReadDV(string ReadCommand)
        {
            bool result = false;
            try
            {
                SqlConnection SCO = ConnectionClass.getconnection();
                SqlCommand delCmd = new SqlCommand(ReadCommand, SCO);
                if (SCO.State != ConnectionState.Open) SCO.Open();
                SqlDataReader r = delCmd.ExecuteReader();

```
            if (r.Read()==true)
            {
                if (SCO.State != ConnectionState.Closed) SCO.Close();
                r.Close();
                result = true;
            }

            else if (r.Read() == false)
            {
                if (SCO.State != ConnectionState.Closed) SCO.Close();
                r.Close();
                result = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }
```