# Error message: not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I get this error message in the following line of my code:

```
public async Task<bool> TestMakePurchase(string productId, string payload)
```

> Error CS0161: 'Game1.TestMakePurchase(string, string)': not all code
>   paths return a value (CS0161)

What does this error message mean and what is wrong with my code?

Full code:

```
 async void CheckPurchase()
    {

        bool purchaseIsSuccessful = await TestMakePurchase("com.website.appName.purchaseName", "");          

        if (purchaseIsSuccessful)
        {               

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }


    public async Task<bool> TestMakePurchase(string productId, string payload)
    {
        var billing = CrossInAppBilling.Current;
        try
        {
            var connected = await billing.ConnectAsync();
            if (!connected)
            {                 
                return false;
            }


            var purchase = await billing.PurchaseAsync(productId, ItemType.InAppPurchase, payload);

            if (purchase == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (InAppBillingPurchaseException purchaseEx)
        {

        }

        finally
        {
            await billing.DisconnectAsync();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If the first `try` catches an exception, there is no `return` statement in the code path.

Comment: You have to return something when an `InAppBillingPurchaseException ` was caught.

Comment: Ask yourself what a "code path" is. If you understand that, then the error message should make sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not all code paths return a value - error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22345051/not-all-code-paths-return-a-value-error)

Comment: I'd recommend placing one return at the end of the method and using a variable to track the current state.

Comment: Completely off topic, just a tip. Your if-else can be simplified... `return purchase != null;`

Comment: Please find my answer with improve logic aswell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to call return on each conditional statement. Simply track the state with a variable (*purchaseState*). It is unclear what should happen when a *InAppBillingPurchaseException* is thrown. I would at least log this error.

```
public async Task<bool> TestMakePurchase(string productId, string payload)
{   
    var purchaseSuccesful = false;
    var billing = CrossInAppBilling.Current;
    try
    {                                   
        if (await billing.ConnectAsync())
        {                 
            var purchase = await billing.PurchaseAsync(productId, ItemType.InAppPurchase, payload);
            purchaseSuccesful = purchase != null;
        }
    }
    catch (InAppBillingPurchaseException purchaseEx)
    {
        //log this error?
    }
    finally
    {
        await billing.DisconnectAsync();
    }

    return purchaseSuccesful;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. How should I log the error? What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Use System.Diagnostics or a logging library e.g. NLog. Just don't ignore errors, as this will make bug fixing difficult.

Answer (score 2):

If the first `try` catches an exception, it potentially bypasses all of you `return` statements. You can fix this by adding a return right at the end of your method:

```
public async Task<bool> TestMakePurchase(string productId, string payload)
{
    var billing = CrossInAppBilling.Current;
    try
    {
        // Snip
    }
    catch (InAppBillingPurchaseException purchaseEx)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        await billing.DisconnectAsync();
    }

    // Add this line
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If exception occur in try block the code exit without any `return` value. Please add `return` statements after `finally` block.

Comment: You should state where the `return` statement needs to go.

Comment: if we don't return from finally its fine but from catch is important

Comment: You can't return inside a `finally` block and returning inside the `catch` wouldn't help either.